# Getting results from quantile regression in LaTex format in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run quantile regressions and save the output to a table in LaTex. I have the following code, which I believe should work:

```
install.packages("quantreg")
library(quantreg)
install.packages('rmarkdown')
require(rms)
```

I am using the `meap01` dataset from the Wooldridge library. 
I ran a quantile regression:

```
ans <- rq(math4 ~ lexppp + lenroll + lunch + lunchsq, tau = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9), data = meap01)
summary(ans)
```

This works perfectly fine. I am able to plot it as well.
Now, I want to obtain the quantile regressions in a table in LaTex. 
I have tried the following:

```
latex.summary.rqs(ans, transpose = TRUE, caption = "table name")
```

I get the following error message:

`Error:` $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

What am I doing wrong? Can this be corrected? Am I missing a package?

Comment: My guess this is error coming from an internal function. This might be something worth contacting the author about.